# Facebook Login with button not requesting all needed read permissions

Tags: swift, facebook, authentication

In my iOS app, I use FBSDKLoginButton to login user and request 4 permissions using the following code:

```
//create facebook login button
    let fbLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton(frame: loginButtonContainer.frame)
    fbLoginButton.readPermissions = ["email","public_profile","user_photos","user_birthday"]
    self.view.addSubview(fbLoginButton)
    fbLoginButton.delegate = self
```

for some test users this works fine and all 4 permissions are requested, but for others - only email & public profile permissions are requested, with no mention of the other two.

any ideas as to a possible reason for the difference ?

Comment: Most probably, the privacy settings set by facebook user can be the reason for this.

Comment: Most likely, you did not submit your app for review yet.